# The named parameter 'badgeColor' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Can someone help me with this. I'm just new in using flutter and I have been developing this app for awhile and encountered this problem. I don't know what seems to be the problem

**the errors of the code**
[image: the errors of the code]

I have not tried anything yet since I don't know any alternative code for this

```
 Consumer<FavsProvider>(
                builder: (_, favs, ch) => Badge(
                  badgeColor: ColorsConsts.cartBadgeColor,
                  animationType: BadgeAnimationType.slide,
                  toAnimate: true,
                  position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 5, end: 7),
                  badgeContent: Text(
                    favs.getFavsItems.length.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using  [badges](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) flutter package's latest version. you need to define BadgeStyle to badgeStyle property. check this and tell me if it solves your problem.

```
Badge(
      position: badges.BadgePosition.topEnd(top: -10, end: -12),
      showBadge: true,
      ignorePointer: false,
      onTap: () {},
      badgeContent: // this enebles what you put inside badge such as numbers, icons etc...
          Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white, size: 10),
      badgeAnimation: badges.BadgeAnimation.rotation(
        animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        colorChangeAnimationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        loopAnimation: false,
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        colorChangeAnimationCurve: Curves.easeInCubic,
      ),
 badgeStyle: BadgeStyle( // this provides you badge shape, color etc. 
        shape: badges.BadgeShape.square,
        badgeColor: Colors.blue,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
        borderGradient: badges.BadgeGradient.linear(
            colors: [Colors.red, Colors.black]),
        badgeGradient: badges.BadgeGradient.linear(
            colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.yellow],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        ),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
child:Container()
)
```

Comment: Should I just paste this one?

Comment: just try it by copying. I also recommend to check package's example codes from github or in pub.dev